# Compare data for two objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have two objects one come from API and contain data for each question and another one I created when the user check the answer

API data

```
"wordList": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "word": "slowly",
        "pos": "adverb"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "word": "ride",
        "pos": "verb"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "word": "bus",
        "pos": "noun"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "word": "commute",
        "pos": "verb"
    },
    ...
]
```

data create after the user check the answer:

```
[
    {
        "word": "slowly",
        "choose": "noun"
    },
    {
        "word": "ride",
        "choose": "noun"
    },
    {
        "word": "bus",
        "choose": "noun"
    },
    {
        "word": "commute",
        "choose": "adjective"
    }
]
```

How can I check IF the answer is correct or not to show user the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will calculate the score for correct answers using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const wordList = [ { "id": 1, "word": "slowly", "pos": "adverb" }, { "id": 2, "word": "ride", "pos": "verb" }, { "id": 3, "word": "bus", "pos": "noun" }, { "id": 4, "word": "commute", "pos": "verb" }, ] 

const answers = [ { "word": "slowly", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "ride", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "bus", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "commute", "choose": "adjective" } ]

const score = answers.reduce((prev, {word, choose}) => {
  return wordList.find(item => word === item.word).pos === choose ? prev + 1: prev
}, 0)

console.log(score);
```

To add isCorrect filed use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const wordList = [ { id: 1, word: "slowly", pos: "adverb", }, { id: 2, word: "ride", pos: "verb", }, { id: 3, word: "bus", pos: "noun", }, { id: 4, word: "commute", pos: "verb", }, ]; const answers = [ { word: "slowly", choose: "noun", }, { word: "ride", choose: "noun", }, { word: "bus", choose: "noun", }, { word: "commute", choose: "adjective", }, ];

const output = answers.map(({ word, choose }) => ({
  word,
  choose,
  isCorrect: wordList.find((item) => word === item.word).pos === choose,
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: if I want add `isCorrect` in `answers ` obj how can update it answers object will be `[ {"word": "slowly", "choose": "adverb", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "ride", "choose": "noun", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "bus", "choose": "verb", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "commute", "choose": "adverb","isCorrect": false}]`

Comment: you are fantastic how can be like you

Comment: @AhmedRadi, It's only I knew what something you didn't know yet. I would like to suggest you to read this book series about JS - https://www.goodreads.com/series/139311-you-don-t-know-js

Comment: thank you for your recommendation I will start studying it immediately ♥

Answer (score 1):

```js
const questions = [ { "id": 1, "word": "slowly", "pos": "adverb" }, { "id": 2, "word": "ride", "pos": "verb" }, { "id": 3, "word": "bus", "pos": "noun" }, { "id": 4, "word": "commute", "pos": "verb" }, ];

const answers = [ { "word": "slowly", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "ride", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "bus", "choose": "noun" }, { "word": "commute", "choose": "adjective" } ];

const result = questions.map((question) => {
  const foundPos = answers.find(answer => answer.word === question.word).choose;
  return `Question ${question.id}: word=${question.word} pos=${question.pos}, and the chosen answer was ` +
  foundPos + ` (${foundPos === question.pos})`;

});

console.log (result);
```

**Expected output:**
0: "Question 1: word=slowly pos=adverb, and the chosen answer was noun (false)"
1: "Question 2: word=ride pos=verb, and the chosen answer was noun (false)"
2: "Question 3: word=bus pos=noun, and the chosen answer was noun (true)"
3: "Question 4: word=commute pos=verb, and the chosen answer was adjective (false)"

Comment: if I want add `isCorrect` in `answers ` obj how can update it answers object will be `[ {"word": "slowly", "choose": "adverb", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "ride", "choose": "noun", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "bus", "choose": "verb", "isCorrect": false}, {"word": "commute", "choose": "adverb","isCorrect": false}]`